# Enlarge input element with animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I wanted to expand the input fields. So this almost works but the efect is "blinky". The field expands and colapses and intereseting makes the second input to go to the next row. Can you give any advise how to do it write or rewrite it in some way!?!?!

Jquery

```
$('#menusearchform .s').mouseenter(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.data('expand')) {
                    $this.data('expand', true);
                    $this.animate({width:'+=32px',left:'-=16px'});
        }
        $this.val("").focus();
}).mouseleave(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.data('expand', false);
        $this.animate({width:'-=32px',left:'+=16px'});
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="divsearch">
     <form method="post" action="index.php" id="menusearchform">

           <input class="s" type="text" value="Search" name="felem1" />
           <input class="s" type="text" value="Search" name="felem2" />

           <input type="submit" value="Search" name="buttonSearch" />
           <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="buttonReset" id="Reset"/>
     </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Jsfiddle link to TC: http://jsfiddle.net/fpgAn/

Comment: I don't understand what this part means "intereseting makes the second input to go to the next row" could you clarify?

Comment: The second input field goes to new line, under the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing you don't want whole form to expand. Maybe this is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/fpgAn/1/

Comment: Actually eactly what I wanted :)